# innerHTML exist but doesn't want write it to other div, other elements are

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, src

I have object with a name of img, and it's taken from DOM, throught onClick function(this) like this:

```
var img = e.lastElementChild;
```

and printing of object returns this (only innerHTML i am giving here):

```
value: <img src="images/p/Ds35.png" alt="C 1" title="C 1" width="500" height="435" itemprop="image" data-highres="http://www.my domain.com/images/o/Ds35.png">
```

and when i try to put this inner in to the other div like this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('GP');
box.innerHTML = img.innerHTML;
```

it's not working, but when i do this:

```
box.innerHTML = img.src;
```

it is working... what is going on?

Comment: There's no such thing as `img.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

there is no innerHTML for `<img />` container.

for example innerHTML for `<div>test</div>`  is a string "test"

so try to use  img.toString()

Comment: nope, doesn't work either. Writes into this div this: [object HTMLImageElement]
also tried: img.innerHTML.toString() and reverse of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
img.outerHTML
```

this one works.

Thanks for trying to help me.